# How to get a single last record from each user using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with personal messages.

I have in it several columns, but required for this question are the next:
    - user id
    - message sent datetime

I want to get the last one message from each user and don't understand how to compile the needed linq query for this aim.

For details, several users have sent me 50-100 messages, but I want to get from each user only the last one by datetime, how do it using linq query?

Comment: Is there any code to show us?

Comment: post your entity model.

Comment: Eh ... Last() on the messages ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358775%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: `var results = personalMessages.GroupBy(pm => pm.User).SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(pm => pm.Sent).Take(1));`

Answer (score 2):

Without any code to show me regarding your schema this is a complete guess but you should simply have to order by the datetime and take the first...

**For a single user:**

```
// Assuming you are using an Entity Framework context?
using (var context = new MyContext()) {
    var lastMessage = context.PersonalMessages.Where(u => u.UserId == userId).OrderByDescending(t => t.SentDate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Get last message for all users:**

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) {
var lastMessages = context.PersonalMessages.GroupBy(pm => pm.UserId).SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(pm => pm.SentDate).Take(1));
}
```

Should be as simple as filtering by the user id, ordering by date and taking the top record.

Comment: That is okay for one user at a time, what about all users at once?